# Php regex plain text to url

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert url plain text to link ( `<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>` ).
I have found this code, but the link stop at the middle of the real link. For example, with https://www.google.com, the result is : https://www.google.com
The preg_replace code is :

```
    $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t&lt;]*)/i", "<a href=\"$3\" >$3</a>", $text);
```

Comment: Putting an &lt; in `[ ]` will match any of the  characters l, t, ;, and & which means that you match will stop at l

Comment: There's gotta be about 5 gazillions libraries which can do this and are well tested...

Comment: @apokryfos, you have find the problem, thanks, I have delete &lt; and now it's work, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?
```

php

```
$text= preg_replace("/((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)/i", "<a href=\"$0\" >$0</a>", $text);
```

Comment: this code :         `$text= preg_replace("(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?", "<a href=\"$3\" >$3</a>", $text);` is not working , nothing text is displaying after

Comment: `$text= preg_replace("/((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)/i", "<a href=\"$0\" >$0</a>", $text);`

Comment: It's working for the link but I have another preg_replace for images, and if I use this code, images aren't displaying